# How should I design this program which state is auto-changed?

Tags: design-patterns

I have something named M, it has three states. When it is at one state, it should do something, then change to another one immediately. And my code can simply satisfy this, but it has a bad effect, at once it starts running, the function will never return.

So, how can I design this program?

```
class M {
    State state;

    func a() {
        doSomethingA();
        self.state = B;
        b();
    }

    func b() {
        doSomethingB();
        self.state = C;
        c();
    }

    func c() {
        doSomethingC();
        self.state = A;
        a();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class M, you have created these 3 methods as a endless loop without any exit condition.

```
a() -> invokes b() -> invokes c() -> invokes a()
```

Let's add an exit condition check as follows.

```
class M {
    State state;

    bool tobeStopped;

    func a() {
        doSomethingA();
        self.state = B;
        if (tobeStopped) {
            tobeStopped = false;
        } else {
            b();
        }
    }

    func b() {
        doSomethingB();
        self.state = C;
        if (tobeStopped) {
            tobeStopped = false;
        } else {
            c();
        }
    }

    func c() {
        doSomethingC();
        self.state = A;
        if (tobeStopped) {
            tobeStopped = false;
        } else {
            a();
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        tobeStopped = true;
    }
}
```

Now, any client who wish to stop it needs to invoke the stop() function.

Make sure that the a(), b() and c() function invokers are not running in the same thread/process which needs to stop it.

Comment: Unfortunately, in real world, these three methods should continuously running until the user stop it.
I tried delegate and notification, but they did not work.

Comment: One simple solution is to use a conditional check, I have added it into the answer now.